# How to fix Fisrt Item always align to Left and Last Item always align to Right Gallery

Tags: android, alignment, gallery, space

Android - How to fix Fisrt Item always align to Left and Last Item always align to Right Gallery

[image]

Comment: place [First item]--[ViewPager]--[Gallery] in a linear layout horizontally and give required weights

Comment: This question is not clear. Is it a `GridView`? Or a `LinearLayout`? Looks like this is not a `ViewPager`

Comment: some code would help answering